# why does not work clean ()?

Tags: python, django

please help to solve the problem . on the page is a form of :

```
from django import forms
from userprofile.models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.conf import settings
import os

class ChangePasswordForm (forms.Form):
    password1 = forms.CharField (widget = forms.PasswordInput ())
    password2 = forms.CharField (widget = forms.PasswordInput ())

def clean (self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    password1 = cleaned_data.get ("password1")
    password2 = cleaned_data.get ("password2")
        
    with open (os.path.join (settings.BASE_DIR, "debug_local.txt"), "wb") as f:
        f.write (bytes (password1, 'UTF- 8') )

    if password1! = password2:
        raise forms.ValudationError ("Passwords must be same")
    else:
        User.set_password (password1)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.template import loader, RequestContext
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from userprofile.forms import UserProfileForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.conf import settings
from userprofile.forms import ChangePasswordForm


def custom_proc (request):
    return {
        'user_profile_show': True,
    }

@ login_required
def password_page (request):
    t = loader.get_template ('password_page.html')
    c = RequestContext (request, {
        'form': ChangePasswordForm,
    }, [Custom_proc])
    return HttpResponse (t.render (c))
```

password_page.py:

```
{% Extends "base.html"%}

{% Block title%} User profile - pass {% endblock%}

{% Block content%}
<h2> pass page </ h2>

{% For field in form%}
{{Field.error}}
{% Endfor%}

<form action="/userprofile/" method="POST"> {% csrf_token%}
{{Form.as_p}}

<input type="submit" value="send" />
</ form>
{% Endblock%}
```

the problem is that not worked function clean (). I'm trying to debug output to a file debug_local.txt value password1. but this file is not written

Comment: Why are you outputting debug to a file?  User a debugger pdb/ipdb to step through your code.  This way you can see what is going on at every step.

Comment: not related to your question but, do not put spaces between your classes or functions names and parameters list ()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up you need to be careful with your whitespace.  This is partly your code style and partly copy and pasting to SO without reformatting.  Eitherway check out the [pep8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines.  They make life easier for everyone.

In your view you are never passing POST'ed data to the form so it is never validating the users input.

Once you have done that you can then validate your form.

Finally once your form is valid you can set the users password

*Disclaimer* It's been a while since I've written a function based view.

```
view.py
@login_required
def password_page(request):
    if requesst.method == 'POST':
        form = ChangePasswordForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.user.set_password(form.cleaned_data.get('password'))
    else
        form = ChangePasswordForm()

    t = loader.get_template('password_page.html')
    c = RequestContext (request, {
        'form': ,
    }, [Custom_proc])
    return HttpResponse (t.render (c))
```

I've removed the password changing in the form.  Personally I would prefer this in the view.

Additionally your `clean()` method MUST return the `cleaned_data`.

```
forms.py
def clean (self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    password1 = cleaned_data.get("password1")
    password2 = cleaned_data.get("password2")

    # DEBUGGING
    # Uncomment this, run your view and head to the
    # console to see what is happening
    # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

    if password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValudationError ("Passwords must be same")

    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: I like your disclaimer!

Comment: Thanks :-) Feels like a long time ago since I was doing that (over and over and over again)

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation on the clean function is wrong. If it is indented this way, it just a function, not a method of your class.

```
class ChangePasswordForm (forms.Form):
    password1 = forms.CharField (widget = forms.PasswordInput ())
    password2 = forms.CharField (widget = forms.PasswordInput ())

    def clean (self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        password1 = cleaned_data.get ("password1")
        password2 = cleaned_data.get ("password2")

        with open (os.path.join (settings.BASE_DIR, "debug_local.txt"), "wb") as f:
            f.write (bytes (password1, 'UTF- 8') )

        if password1! = password2:
            raise forms.ValudationError ("Passwords must be same")
        else:
            User.set_password (password1)
```